# Error: an object reference is required to access non static member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 input;

    void Update () {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        rigidbody.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add more information about your question! What are you trying to achieve? Did you try anything else?

Answer (score 0):

As of Unity 5 `UnityEngine.Component.rigibody` has been deprecated and using it will cause a compiler error. Instead you need to use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`.  So in your case, your code would looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
public float moveSpeed;

private Vector3 input;

    void Update () 
    {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```